# Spring Transaction Management + Active MQ + Datasource

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-transactions

Here is the flow:

1. Begin Transaction.
2. Message put into the queue but not ready to be dequeue. (Right now I don't know how to achieve it)
3. (i)End Transaction - Successful: Message will be available to be dequeue.
4. (ii) Rollback: Message will be removed from queue.
5. Message successfully de-queue by the Listener.

I can configure Spring Transaction Manager for hibernate entities. Same way I can Active MQ available for `JMSTransactionManager`. But the big question is 
How would JMSTransactionManager will know the state of `HibernateTransactionManager`? How would these two interact?

```
Note: I am using Tomcat managed datasources for Hibernate entities. Apache Camel support is also available in project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an XA-enabled transaction manager, and Spring doesn't come with any. So either deploy your app in a Java EE application server, or embed a stand-alone transaction manager like Bitronix.

Comment: Ok. Lets say I get XA enabled manager. What is the next step from here?

Comment: You read its documentation carefully, and follow the instructions.